# Validating Strings with underscores using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

How do I validate names with a Regular Expression when they have the following names

```
A_106_20120101_10_20.txt
B_106_20120205_10_20aha.txt
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those two are the only type of pattern you would like to match something like so: `^[A-Z](_[A-Za-z0-9]+)+\.txt$` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another, more specific stab:

```
^[A-Z]_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+[A-Za-z]*\.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear as to desired result, but please try this

```
"\\w_\\d{3}_\\d{8}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}.*"
```